# How do I use command substitution in find -exec?

Tags: find, command-substitution

If I just use `basename {} .txt`, it will work:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec basename {} .txt \;
```

It will just print `xxx` instead of `./xxx.txt`. If I use `$(basename {} .txt)` in the `-exec` option, it will fail:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec echo "$(basename {} .txt)" \;
```

It will just print `./xxx.txt`

How can I solve this problem? I hope I can use `$(basename {} .txt)` as parameters for other cmd. Do I have to do `sh -c` or pipe `-exec basename {} \;` with xargs?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use sh or pipe it out. Process substitution takes place before find starts.

Comment: Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If other reading this don't need the suffix-stripping capabilities of `basename`, you can use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` as that holds the current file (not path) in `{}` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300696/328817))

Comment: an excellent question & answer about this topic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/93768

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
find -iname "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'for f do basename -- "$f" .txt;done' sh {} +
```

Your first command failed, because `$(...)` run in subshell, which treat `{}` as literal. so `basename {} .txt` return `{}`, your `find` became:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec echo {} \;
```

which print file name matched.

Comment: I think you're missing a path on that proposed solution.  Perhaps it should start `find . -iname`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can still use `$()` for command substitution if you use `sh -c` and single quotes:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename {} .txt)"' \;
```

The single quotes prevent the main shell from executing the sub-command inside `$()` so it can instead be executed by `sh -c` *after* the `find` command has replaced `{}` with the file name. See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15627675/490396) for a more thorough explanation.

Note that you can also add double quotes inside the `$()` to handle spaces in file names:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename "{}" .txt)"' \;
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead, there is another way by using bash pipelines and `xargs` command:

```
    find . -iname '*.txt' | xargs -L1 -I{} basename "{}"
```

In the `xargs` command above:

The `-L1` argument means executing the output of the `find` command line by line.

The `-I{}` argument is intended to wrap the output of the `find` command with double quotes to avoid bash word splitting (when filenames contain whitespace).

Comment: I got this warning: `xargs: warning: options --max-lines and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-lines value`. How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @an9wer, as a pipeline is a lot easier (to type, to remember, to read, etc) though I'd try to adhere to posix xargs and use nil character as separator; xargs on alpine, for example, doesn't have the `-L1` flag, which means that you must explicitly flag for nil in both the `find` and `xargs` command.
*If you're talking about running adhoc commands, then ignore this, but if this is a script that is developed on something that is not your production environment, and assuming your production environment never changes, then this is a really big deal.*

Same as @an9swer, but with nil character as delimiter, using `-n` flag to feed one result, at a time, as an argument of `basename`. We also don't need the template flag `-I`, since its inferred and the default behavior.

```bsh
find . -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -- basename
```

An additional advantage to the above, is that xargs allows for executing the passed statement, in parallel, which means you could run the above in parallel, up to the number of cores that you have, to feed to some downstream process. If you are dealing with a number-approaching-infinity files or if workflow optimization is important, this is a big, low-hanging-fruit win

And yes, I am showing off a little, but its ok, because I am fine with being petty (at times).