# Why does a for-loop not require explicitly specifying the set of values of the loop variable?

Tags: bash

I read a command from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175845/674

Why can

```
$ bash -c 'for f do echo "$f";done' bash a b c
a
b
c
```

output the same as

```
$ bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo "$f";done' bash a b c
a
b
c
```

?

Why does a for-loop not require  explicitly specifying

- the set of values of the loop variable, as `in "$@"` and
- `;` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the POSIX grammar [allows it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).

> The format for the for loop is as follows:
>
> ```
> for name [ in [word ... ]]
> do
>     compound-list
> done
> ```
>
> First, the list of words following in shall be expanded to generate a list of items. Then, the variable name shall be set to each item, in turn, and the compound-list executed each time. If no items result from the expansion, the compound-list shall not be executed. Omitting:
>
> ```
> in word...
> ```
>
> shall be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> in "$@"
> ```

The formal grammar for the `for` loop looks like

```
for_clause       : For name                                      do_group
                 | For name                       sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in          sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group
```

`For` is a grammar token for the string `for`. `sequential_sep` is either `;` or one or several newlines and `linebreak` is a single optional newline. The `do_group` at the end is your `do ...; done`.

This means that the valid `for` loops are

1. Loop over `"$@"`:

   ```
   for name do ...; done
   ```
2. Loop over `"$@"`:

   ```
   for name; do ...; done
   ```
3. Loop over empty list:

   ```
   for name in; do ...; done
   ```
4. Loop over non-empty list:

   ```
   for name in word-list; do ...; done
   ```

The third form is valid but doesn't do anything. It exists to allow loops whose word-list expands to nothing.

Comment: Another form that works, although IIRC is not documented is `for i ; { echo "$i"; }`. Seen that somewhere on one of Stephane's answers

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That would work in `bash` and `zsh`, but is not POSIX.  Both `dash` and `yash` chokes on it.

Comment: And it works in `ksh93` where it probably came from.

Answer (score 7):

From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
>
> The list of words
> following in is expanded, generating a list of items. The variable
> name is set to each element of this list in turn, and list is executed
> each time. **If the in word is omitted, the for command executes list
> once for each positional parameter that is set** (see PARAMETERS below). ...

Then from the parameters section:

> A positional parameter is a parameter denoted by one or more digits,
> other than the single digit 0. **Positional parameters are assigned from
> the shell's arguments when it is invoked**, and may be reassigned using
> the set builtin command. ...

In summary, the `in` keyword and following semicolon are optional. If you omit the `in` keyword, the parameters for the `for` loop are taken from the arguments passed to the shell. Therefore, the two code samples you provide are equivalent.

Comment: If the positional parameters are set with `set` within the script, the loop without the list will not loop over the arguments of the script, but over the new positional parameters.